# Who am I, Hacking you everyday?

Tags: riddle

> I am known to hack the network 
>   but I never do
>
> Yet I can be number one 
>   or number two if bored
>
> My grade is always a C plus 
>   never above that dang C
>
> I'm more famous here 
>   than the whole wide world
>
> I rhyme with cheat 
>   though I never do
>
> I got so much gold 
>   I got more than all your medals combined
>
> I can see sharper than all of you 
>   and as famous as Chuck Norris

Who am I?

Hint:

> Think locally... what is here? And what really familar network am I talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> Jon Skeet.

I am known to hack the network
but I never do

> He is a member of 15 communities in the Stack Exchange network.

Yet I can be number one
or number two if bored

> He is the top ranked user.

My grade is always a C plus
never above that dang C

> I'm not sure of this one, unless it has to do with his programming. He doesn't use B?

I'm more famous here
than the whole wide world

> He's a well known user of Stack Exchange

I rhyme with cheat
though I never do

> Skeet rhymes with cheat.

I got so much gold
I got more than all your medals combined

> He has 430 gold medals, which is more gold medals than many users have total.

I can see sharper than all of you
and as famous as Chuck Norris

> He is an author of a C# book.

Comment: congrats.looks like a better answer than mine! but still some parts doesn't make much sense. for example "I got so much gold I got more than all your medals combined" is simply not true if you combine all medals of other users.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> heat

I am known to hack the network

but I never do

> Sun can melt the whole earth if it comes a bit near.

Yet I can be number one

or number two if bored

> In night it will be number two because number one is moon.

My grade is always a C plus

never above that dang C

> Heat movie has C+ grade in [avclub website](http://www.avclub.com/review/the-heat-99486)!

I rhyme with cheat

though I never do

> Heat rhyme with cheat but it never cheats (Sun never leave us without heat)

I got so much gold

I got more than all your medals combined

> Who else can bring more heat (which is source of any sort of energy) to us? Also it can refer to golden color of sun

I can see sharper than all of you

> maybe refers to heat vison AKA Infrared thermography which allow to see at night

and as famous as Chuck Norris

> Maybe refer to the heat movie which is as famous as Chuck norris.